# Search whitespace in string inC

Tags: c, string, whitespace, scanf

problem is when I try to enter a string with space compiler render that as separate 2 strings. But requirement is whenever there is a space in string don't treat it as 2 strings,but rather a single string. The program should print yes only if my four inputs are MAHIRL,CHITRA,DEVI and C. my code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char str1[10],str2[10],str3[10],str4[10];
    scanf("%s",str1);
    scanf("%s",str2);
    scanf("%s",str3);
    scanf("%s",str4);
    if(strcmp(str1,"MAHIRL")==0 && strcmp(str2,"CHITRA")==0 && strcmp(str3,"DEVI")==0 && strcmp(str4,"C")==0 ){
        printf("yes");
    }
    else{
        printf("no");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried using strtok() and strpbrk(), but I'm not quite sure how to implement them in my code. Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%s` directive matches characters up to a whitespace before storing them, so it is not possible to get lines of input this way. There are other ways to use `scanf()` to read lines of input, but these are error-prone, and this is really not the right tool for the job.

Better to use `fgets()` to fetch a line of input to a buffer, and `sscanf()` to parse the buffer. Since the requirement here is that four strings are entered, this is a simple problem using this method:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str1[10],str2[10],str3[10],str4[10];
    char buffer[100];

    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in fgets()\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (sscanf(buffer, "%9s%9s%9s%9s", str1, str2, str3, str4) == 4) {
        if (strcmp(str1,"MAHIRL") == 0 &&
            strcmp(str2,"CHITRA") == 0 &&
            strcmp(str3,"DEVI") == 0 &&
            strcmp(str4,"C") == 0 ){
            printf("yes\n");
        } else {
            printf("no\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("Input requires 4 strings\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

An additional character array is declared, `buffer[]`, with enough extra space to contain extra input; this way, if the user enters some extra characters, it is less likely to interfere with the subsequent behavior of the program. Note that `fgets()` returns a null pointer if there is an error, so this is checked for; an error message is printed and the program exits if an error is encountered here.

Then `sscanf()` is used to parse `buffer[]`. Note here that maximum widths are specified with the `%s` directives to avoid buffer overflow. The `fgets()` function stores the newline in `buffer[]` (if there is room), but using `sscanf()` in this way avoids needing to further handle this newline character.

Also note that `sscanf()` returns the number of successful assignments made; if this return value is not `4`, the input was not as expected and the values held by `str1`,..., `str4` should not be used.

### Update

Looking at this question again, I am not sure that I have actually answered it. At first I thought that you wanted to use `scanf()` to read a line of input, and extract the strings from this. But you say: "whenever there is a space in string don't treat it as 2 strings", even though none of the test input in your example code contains such spaces.

One option for reading user input containing spaces into a string would be to use a separate call to `fgets()` for each string. If you store the results directly in `str1`,...,`str4` you will need to remove the newline character kept by `fgets()`. What may be a better approach would be to store the results in `buffer` again, and then to use `sscanf()` to extract the string, this time including spaces. This can be done using the scanset directive:

```
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
sscanf(buffer, " %9[^\n]", str1);
```

The format string here contains a leading space, telling `sscanf()` to skip over zero or more leading whitespace characters. The `%[^\n]` directive tells `sscanf()` to match characters, including spaces, until a newline is encountered, storing them in `str1[]`. Note that a maximum width of 9 is specified, leaving room for the `\0` terminator.

If you want to be able to enter multiple strings, each containing spaces, on the same *line* of user input, you will need to choose a delimiter. Choosing a comma, this can be accomplished with:

```
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
sscanf(buffer, " %9[^,], %9[^,], %9[^,], %9[^,\n]", str1, str2, str3, str4);
```

Here, there is a leading space as before, to skip over any stray whitespace characters (such as `\n` characters) that may be in the input. The `%[^,]` directives tell `sscanf()` to match characters until a comma is encountered, storing them in the appropriate array (`str1[]`,..., `str3[]`). The following `,`  tells `sscanf()` to match one comma and zero or more whitespace characters before the next scanset directive. The final directive is `%[^,\n]`, telling `sscanf()` to match characters until either a comma or a newline are encountered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str1[10],str2[10],str3[10],str4[10];
    char buffer[100];

    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in fgets()\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Each individual string str1,..., str4 may contain spaces */
    if (sscanf(buffer, " %9[^,], %9[^,], %9[^,], %9[^,\n]",
               str1, str2, str3, str4) == 4) {
        if (strcmp(str1,"test 1") == 0 &&
            strcmp(str2,"test 2") == 0 &&
            strcmp(str3,"test 3") == 0 &&
            strcmp(str4,"test 4") == 0 ){
            printf("yes\n");
        } else {
            printf("no\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("Input requires 4 comma-separated strings\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a sample interaction with this final program:

```
test 1, test 2, test 3, test 4
yes
```

Comment: @AbhishekThakur-- You have already accepted my answer, but I am afraid that I may have misunderstood your question. I have updated my answer to consider how to read strings containing spaces, even from a line of user input.

Comment: thank you very much. I made some adjustments and things worked!

Answer (score 5):

> *problem is when I try to enter a string with space compiler render that as separate 2 strings*

That's not a problem, that's **the** feature / behaviour of `%s` format specifier with `scanf()`. You cannot read space-delimited input using that.

For conversion specifier `s`, chapter §7.21.6.2, C11

> `s` Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters. [...]

So, the matching ends as soon as it hits a white-space character, here, the `space`.

If you have to read a *line* (i.e., input terminated by *newline*), use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.

Answer (score 0):

While reading strings from user, use __fpurge(stdin) function from stdio_ext.h. This flushes out the stdin. When you are entering a string, you press enter at last, which is also a character. In order to avoid that, we use fpurge function.

```
scanf("%s",str1);
__fpurge(stdin);
scanf("%s",str2);
__fpurge(stdin);
scanf("%s",str3);
__fpurge(stdin);
scanf("%s",str4);
__fpurge(stdin);
```

Also if you want to input a string from user containing spaces, use following:

```
scanf("%[^\n]", str1);
```

This will not ignore the spaces you enter while inputting string.

EDIT: Instead of using fpurge function, one can use following code:

```
while( getchar() != '\n' );
```

Comment: There is no need to clear the input stream of whitespace characters before using the `%s` directive with `scanf()` , since this directive _automatically_ ignores leading whitespace characters. Also, `__fpurge()` is a GNU extension, not part of Standard C; there are better, more portable ways of accomplishing this.

Comment: Yes, this loop is a step in the right direction. But there is something critical missing: `getchar()` can return `EOF` in the event of an I/O error, or if a file has been redirected to `stdin`, or if the user signals `EOF` from the keyboard. Thus, the loop must _also_ check for `EOF` to avoid an infinite loop. Further, the value of `EOF` may not fit in a `char`, so an `int` (which is the return type for `getchar()`) must be used: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);`.